# Netezza Stored procedure DB_NAME as an argument

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, netezza

HI everyone I wrote a kind of a simple procedure in Aginity(Netezza). The stored procedure basically has to load data from one db.table1 to db2.table2. Simple right? Then then the procedure - procedure 1 takes in an argument, which is the name of the database(db).

This is the error message I get whenever I try to run my procedure:
/*
ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  syntax error, unexpected VARIABLE, expecting BEGIN at or near "db_arg"
*/

The procedure looks like something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD_data_proc(CHARACTER VARYING(15))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE 
db_arg CHARACTER VARYING(15);
```

/* if I remove above declaration I get the following error message: ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  ResolveCatalog: error retrieving database 'STG_DB_NAME' */

```
db_arg ALIAS FOR $1;
```

/* and bunch of other arguments and declarations */

```
BEGIN
```

/* logic here if then else statements */

```
END;
END_PROC;
```

Did anyone encounter this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your description what the actual NZPLSQL code is, but I can reproduce your first error using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD_DATA_PROC(CHARACTER VARYING(15))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE 
    db_arg CHARACTER VARYING(15);
    db_arg alias for $1;
BEGIN
    db_arg := 'SYSTEM';
    RAISE NOTICE '%', db_arg;
    RETURN 0;
END;
END_PROC;
```

Note there is a double declaration of the same variable name in the DECLARE block. This is not allowed, and this causes:

```
ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  syntax error, unexpected VARIABLE, expecting BEGIN at or near "db_arg"
```

Removing one of the declarations will allow the procedure to complete.

IBM docs on NZPLSQL regarding parameter passing to stored procedures is available here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_parameter_passing.html
and here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_arg_list.html

As for:

```
ERROR [HY000] ERROR: ResolveCatalog: error retrieving database 'STG_DB_NAME'
```

This occurs when I attempt to call a non-existent stored procedure, in a non-existent schema of a non-existent database such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD_DATA_PROC(CHARACTER VARYING(15))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE 
    db_arg alias for $1;
BEGIN
    CALL UNKNOWNDB.UNKNOWN_SCHEMA.UNKNOWN_STORED_PROC(1234,5678,7890,123456,1234567);
END;
END_PROC;
```

which gives me:

```
ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  ResolveCatalog: error retrieving database 'UNKNOWNDB'
```

Hopefully this helps to explain the errors and how to avoid them.

Comment: You are spot on the first error message, double declaration was just a desperate attempt solve a problem. Second error, the parameter 'bd_name' was passed, but netezza did not see it as a 'database_name', so I had to run a dynamic query whenever I used the db_name parameter

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out... you can pass db_names as arguments to the netezza stored procedure but every time you use the argument inside the procedure, you have to use a dynamic query...

Hope this helps somebody, someday.